# Which hardware setup is better for workstation/server to run R & RStudio on Linux

Tags: r, rstudio, hardware

I have looked up for specs of computers to run R & RStudio and found that Linux (Ubuntu) based machine should be the choice. I talked to a supplier that won a tender at my university for computer purchases and was offered (within my budget, quite low) two choices.
**Which one is better**:
(1) HP Z4 workstation with Intel Xeon W-2223 (4 cores, 8 threads, clock frequency 3.6-3.9 GHz), 128 GB (4x 32GB ECC R) RAM, video nVIDIA T400 4GB, SSD 512GB
or
(2) HP Z4 workstation with Intel i9-10900X (10 cores, 20 threads, clock frequency 3.7-4.7 GHz), 32 GB (2x 16GB) RAM, video  nVIDIA T400 4GB, SSD 512GB.
The difference is in processor and RAM, neither of them is on the Ubuntu certified hardware list. I plan to set it as a server (RStudio Server).
Could anyone have any comments or advice? Which one to choose from the two?

Comment: You might have better luck with this question in a different forum: https://superuser.com

Comment: @JohnPolo thank you fot the hint